# Is "暴走する" accurately translated as "Out of control" or a synonym of such, in this context?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to figure out the epithet here, the English version has "Finance-controlled Golem", which is a sensible epithet in context, but I'm quite sure that it's not a proper translation... I know that "古代兵器" is Ancient Weapon... So how would I translate "暴走する"?:

Wiktionary has [Drive Recklessly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9A%B4%E8%B5%B0), but I don't think "Recklessly Operated Ancient Weapon" is an correct epithet for Arma, given that she's actually being remotely controlled into being an *effective*, violent attacker...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think "out of control" is a valid translation.  My dictionary also has "runaway", like "runaway train" (暴走電車), and "running wild".  Since the object in question is an ancient weapon, I think you could safely infer "rampage" as well.